# Sylius customizing model dose not working

Tags: php, frameworks, symfony4, sylius, sylius-1.3

It's my class file Country.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Sylius\Component\Addressing\Model\Country as BaseCountry;

class Country extends BaseCountry {

/**
 * @var bool
 */
private $flag;

/**
 * @return bool|null
 */
public function getFlag(): ?bool {
    return $this->flag;
}

/**
 * @param bool $flag
 */
public function setFlag(bool $flag): void {
    $this->flag = $flag;
   }

}
```

It's my orm file. *AppBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/Country.orm.yml*

```
App\Entity\Country:
   type: entity
   table: sylius_country
   fields:
       flag:
           type: boolean
           nullable: true
```

It's my config file. *config/_sylius.yml*

```
sylius_addressing:
   resources:
       country:
           classes:
               model: App\Entity\Country
```

It's all ok like sylius customizing model but it's not working.

Comment: Which version of Sylius do you use? Please be more explicit. What exactly is "not working"?

Comment: i am using sylius 1.3 version.? sylius Customizing Model extended does not working.

Answer (score 0):

> It's my orm file. AppBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/Country.orm.yml

The orm file should be placed at `src\Resources\config\doctrine` for v1.3

Also, what's the result of `php bin/console debug:config sylius_addressing`?

//2018-12-18

Maybe try:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Sylius\Component\Addressing\Model\Country as BaseCountry;

/**
 * Class Country
 * @package App\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="sylius_country")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Country extends BaseCountry {
```

Comment: it was same path src\Resources\config\doctrine.but that's does not work.

Comment: Any error message?
What is the result of `php bin/console debug:config sylius_addressing`?

Comment: when i run this command 'php bin/console debug:config sylius_addressing' then showing country classes is ...country:
            classes:
                model: Sylius\Component\Addressing\Model\Country
                interface: Sylius\Component\Addressing\Model\CountryInterface
                controller: Sylius\Bundle\ResourceBundle\Controller\ResourceController
                factory: Sylius\Component\Resource\Factory\Factory
                form: Sylius\Bundle\AddressingBundle\Form\Type\CountryType

Comment: Have a try to add the annotations on Country.php (see my update with the tag //2018-12-18 above)

Comment: Does it solved? I've found your config file location seems wrong. You should place under packages folder: `config\packages\_sylius.yaml`

Comment: I want to do sylius existing entity extend. my understanding was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

1. `type: mappedSuperclass` in doctrine mapping
2. Make sure `AppBundle` extends `AbstractResourceBundle`
3. Make sure `AppBundle` has `protected $mappingFormat = ResourceBundleInterface::MAPPING_YAML;`